# WifiConfiguration is not been accepted by Android 7

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I was developing some app where I try to create a wifi interface, and connect my payment device to it.

My code is working in Android 8 (A920 Pro), but it doesn't work on Android 7 (A920):

All the logic is manage by my viewModel, which is the following:

SharedViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    private val wifiManager: WifiManager =
        context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

    private val _isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    fun launchWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _isLoading.emit(true)
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
                wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return@launch
            }
            val wifiConfiguration = createWifiConfiguration()
            try {
                connectWifi(
                    context = context,
                    wifiConfiguration = wifiConfiguration
                ).also {
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _isLoading.emit(false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createWifiConfiguration(): WifiConfiguration {
        /**
         * Set the following wifi params:
         * Seguridad: 802.1x EAP
         * Método EAP: EAP PEAP
         * Autenticación fase 2: MSCHAPv2
         * Certificado CA: Sin certificado
         * Identidad: ***********
         * Identidad anónima: Nada
         * Contraseña: ******
         *
         */
        val wifiEnterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
        val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
        wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.identity = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_USER +"\""
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.password = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP)
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey ="\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS+"\""

        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)

        return wifiConfiguration
    }

    private fun connectWifi(
        context: Context,
        wifiConfiguration: WifiConfiguration,
    ) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled){
            wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
        }
        //add the network
        val ssid = wifiManager.addNetwork(
            wifiConfiguration
        )
        //Enable all the interface
        wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
            it.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        }

        wifiManager.disconnect()
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(ssid, true) // this initiates the connection
        wifiManager.reconnect()

    }

    fun getNetworkId(context: Context, ssid: String): Int {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return -1
        }
        val configurations = wifiManager.configuredNetworks
        for (config in configurations) {
            if (config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals(ssid, true)) {
                return config.networkId
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

Regarding my MainActivity class which contains the UI, is quite simple, showing a circle loading component, until the process is finnish.

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setUI()
        processWifiConfiguration(applicationContext)
    }

    private fun processWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
       try {
           viewModel.launchWifiConfiguration(context = context)
       }catch (e:NullPointerException){
           e.printStackTrace()
       }

    }

    private fun setUI() {
        setContent {
            val viewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
            val context = LocalContext.current
            WifiCepsaManagerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    if(isLoading){
                        CenterLoadingText(applicationContext.getString(R.string.wait))
                    }else{
                        //Finnish activity
                        context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
                        this.finish()
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CenterLoadingText(name: String) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
        Text(
            text = name,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

Show after a lot of reading about Wifi managment in android using WifiConfiguration, I have concluded the problem is about the WifiConfiguration object is not been accepted by Android 7. In order to solve it, I try removing some params of configuration obeject like the 'allowedPairwiseCiphers' or put the same 'allowedProtocols' than my home Wifi.

I also try to removing some params which I needed like 'allowedKeyManagement' but doesn't work either, besides I need that kind of configuration.

I am really stack into this isssue since some days ago, and I am start to run out of choices.

If you get into a trubble like this before I can bring some light into this, take thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add more details regarding your issue. What do you mean by "my code doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Are you seeing unintended behaviour?

Comment: Additionally you may want to read the [API diff report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/26/changes/changes-summary) for SDK 26 to see what functionality you use that was only added in Android 8.